# Customize Mat-checkbox Indeterminate icon

Tags: css, angular, checkbox, angular-material

Default Icon for `MatCheckbox Indeterminate` is like below:

[image: Default]

I want to customize it to look like this:

[image: Customized checkbox]

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried before posting here.

Comment: @DimitarSpasovski it's tagged angular. I'm pretty sure anyone familiar with angular material and css can determine what she means from the image and the property. Evident by the answer below.

Comment: @Roj It does not matter if the question is easy to answer. The problem with this question is that the poster shows no effort to solve the problem that is posted here. As far as we know, she didn't even try to solve the problem. We need to understand that stackoverflow is not a code writing service. That is why this question has 3 downvotes. If you ask me, I would advice people to not answer questions of this type, because they will only increase the number of "help vampires". As you can see, the op started asking for more help in the comments on the answer bellow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this code to your `styles.css`:

```css
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  border: 2px solid #757575;
  background: #68d0e5;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 0);
  padding: 30%;
}
```

Here's a working example: https://angular-ve9hge-zjec5e.stackblitz.io

Comment: Do you have any idea how can we do similar thing for <input> checkbox.